# Perl not selecting defined value with "||" in subroutines or hashes

Tags: perl

I'm running a simple script that will assign a variable to one value if a value is defined, most simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':default';

my $x;
my $y = $x || 3;
say $y; # prints 3, as it should, because $x isn't defined
$x = 9;
$y = $x || 3;
say $y; # prints 9, as it should, because $x is defined
```

However, when I attempt to use the same syntax in a subroutine, it works in reverse:

```
sub subr {
    my ($args) = @_;
    my $min = $args->{min} || 4; # returns 4, not $args->{min}
    say $min;
}

subr({
    min => 0 # prints 4, not 0
});
```

The same problem occurs with hashes as in the subroutine:

```
my %h = ( 'a' => 0);
$y = $h{a} || 7;
say $y; # prints 7, which isn't correct, it should be 0
if (defined $h{a}) {
    $y = $h{a};
} else {
    $y = 1;
}
say $y; # 0, which is correct
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Why does

```
my $var = $something || number
```

work differently with hashes or hash references in subroutines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`||` is the or operator. It examines the left-hand-side for truthiness, not for definedness. For a binary operator that tests definedness, you want `//` (available since Perl v5.10).

More in [`perlop`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Logical-Defined-Or)